# Error in View : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, rstudio

Below is a subsample of my data set (only 2 rows by 215 columns). I am trying to view them on RStudio but it gives me the following error:

```
Error in View : undefined columns selected
```

Do not really know what is going on. The whole set is 7786 rows by 215 columns. Viewing it works fine, however, when doing any kind of subsetting or removing one row it is no longer want to view.

```
structure(list(`NA` = structure(c(16343, 16344), class = "Date"), 
AVON = c("615.5", "621.5"), BA. = c("471.5", "463.2"), CMRG = c("224.5", 
"224.5"), COB = c("291.10000000000002", "283.5"), MGGT = c("451.2", 
"444.7"), QQ. = c("224.5", "223.5"), RR. = c("953.65", "933.38"
), SNR = c("268.2", "264.7"), ULE = c("1771", "1746"), GKN = c("319.2", 
"311.5"), BRAG = c("617", "603"), BVIC = c("668", "661"), 
CCH = c("1333", "1327"), DGE = c("1785", "1760.5"), SAB = c("3428", 
"3383"), STCK = c("291.60000000000002", "294"), ALNT = c("328", 
"321"), CAR = c("125", "124.5"), CRDA = c("2053", "1990"), 
ELM = c("255.5", "254.5"), JMAT = c("2919", "2825"), SYNT = c("212", 
"210.8"), VCTA = c("1606", "1605"), DIA = c("901", "924"), 
DNO = c("611", "611"), E2V = c("161", "160.5"), HLMA = c("612", 
"598.5"), HTY = c("309.8", "308"), MGAM = c("296.8", "289.40000000000003"
), OXFD = c("1020", "1035"), RSHW = c("1630", "1625"), SXS = c("1808", 
"1778"), TTG = c("166.75", "167.5"), XAR = c("376", "367"
), X = c("1527", "1520"), ABF = c("2679", "2654"), AE = c("633.5", 
"640"), CARM = c("1647", "1637"), CWK = c("1328", "1320"), 
DCG = c("383.75", "369"), DVO = c("237.75", "231"), GNCL = c("234", 
"229.6"), HFG = c("416", "411"), FD = c("36.5", "34.75"), 
TATE = c("591.5", "585"), MNDI = c("1011", "1012"), BI = c("616", 
"620"), REX = c("491.8", "483.5"), RC = c("559", "540"), 
SMDS = c("266.3", "257"), SMIN = c("1264", "1250"), VSVS = c("451.8", 
"438.40000000000003"), AGA = c("163.25", "160.25"), BDEV = c("396.1", 
"389.3"), BKG = c("2250", "2224"), BLWY = c("1567", "1558"
), BVS = c("779", "771"), CRST = c("325", "314.60000000000002"
), GLSN = c("393.5", "388.5"), MCB = c("83.53", "83.29"), 
SN = c("1334", "1309"), RB. = c("5350", "5305"), RDW = c("280.7", 
"273.8"), TW. = c("112.8", "111.8"), BODY = c("668.5", "647"
), FENR = c("317.60000000000002", "313.10000000000002"), 
GDWN = c("3500", "3500"), HILS = c("561", "561.5"), IMI = c("1230", 
"1206"), MRO = c("247.70000000000002", "246"), VAR = c("304", 
"300.75"), RNO = c("56", "54.5"), RTRK = c("2765", "2736"
), SFR = c("63.5", "64"), SRX = c("2826", "2812"), TRI = c("105.75", 
"105"), VTC = c("613.5", "612"), WEIR = c("2502", "2430"), 
EVR = c("130", "123.60000000000001"), FXO = c("112.3", "105.10000000000001"
), BBA = c("325", "326"), BMS = c("494.38", "492"), CKN = c("2350", 
"2341"), FSHR = c("1326", "1294"), RMG = c("392.2", "399.7"
), STOB = c("111", "109"), UKM = c("473.88", "467"), WIN = c("136.25", 
"137.5"), GAW = c("597.5", "585"), HTM = c("131.5", "129.25"
), `NA` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), AAL = c("1384", 
"1363.5"), ABG = c("218.8", "209.1"), ANTO = c("721", "702"
), AF = c("131.5", "130.25"), AQ = c("18.5", "18.75"), ARMS = c("69", 
"62.25"), BLT = c("1715", "1690.5"), CEY = c("61.15", "61"
), FRES = c("760", "747"), GEMD = c("192", "191.75"), GLEN = c("343.2", 
"336.45"), HOC = c("135.30000000000001", "130.19999999999999"
), KAZ = c("263.39999999999998", "260.10000000000002"), KMRL = c("9.5", 
"9.3000000000000007"), LMI = c("185.8", "176.8"), NWR = c("1.97", 
"1.82"), `NA` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), DL = c("190.20000000000002", 
"190"), OG = c("22", "24"), OLY = c("516", "496.6"), RIO = c("3031.5", 
"3020"), RRS = c("4209", "4154"), VED = c("998.5", "974.5"
), AFR = c("103.5", "109.4"), BG. = c("1140", "1093"), B. = c("453.45", 
"452.75"), CNE = c("176.5", "171.6"), ENQ = c("109.60000000000001", 
"107.8"), EXI = c("157", "150"), HDY = c("102", "99.75"), 
JKX = c("48.25", "47"), OHR = c("229.3", "220.9"), MO = c("333", 
"324.7"), RDSA = c("2358.5", "2331"), RDSB = c("2437", "2418.5"
), SIA = c("381", "377.90000000000003"), SMDR = c("100", 
"98.5"), TLW = c("644.5", "631"), AMEC = c("1104", "1077"
), CIU = c("283.5", "275.75"), GMS = c("157", "157"), HTG = c("892.5", 
"876"), LAM = c("163.25", "160"), FC = c("1037", "1011"), 
WG. = c("759.5", "743"), BRBY = c("1511", "1476"), ZC = c("365.7", 
"366"), SG = c("1133", "1126"), TED = c("1863", "1862"), 
ULVR = c("2585", "2547"), AZN = c("4441.5", "4360.5"), BTG = c("700", 
"697.5"), CIR = c("304", "300"), DH = c("758", "753"), GNS = c("1130", 
"1130"), GSK = c("1413", "1414"), HIK = c("1733", "1715"), 
SH = c("5340", "5310"), SK = c("329.25", "319"), VEC = c("132", 
"132"), AGK = c("1548", "1528"), AHT = c("1043", "1024"), 
ATK = c("1317", "1323"), BAB = c("1092", "1085"), BNZL = c("1610", 
"1597"), BRAM = c("376", "374"), BRSN = c("980", "979"), 
CLLN = c("304.60000000000002", "304.3"), CMS = c("59.75", 
"59.5"), CNCT = c("149.25", "151"), CI = c("1164", "1165"
), CTR = c("259.5", "255"), DCC = c("3422", "3405"), DLAR = c("477", 
"478"), DLM = c("689.5", "685"), ECOM = c("223", "219.8"), 
ESNT = c("797.5", "792.5"), EXO = c("176.5", "180"), EXN = c("983.5", 
"968"), GFS = c("250.70000000000002", "251.6"), GFTU = c("626", 
"616"), HAS = c("116.3", "115.7"), HRG = c("45.75", "45.75"
), HSV = c("319.7", "319"), HWDN = c("339.1", "335"), HYC = c("749", 
"748"), IRV = c("599.5", "592.5"), ITRK = c("2621", "2631"
), LVD = c("201.75", "201.5"), MER = c("435", "436.75"), 
MMC = c("25.25", "25"), MNZS = c("569", "575.5"), MI = c("418.6", 
"421"), MTO = c("287.90000000000003", "286.60000000000002"
), NTG = c("483.8", "481.3"), AY = c("983.5", "989"), FL = c("182", 
"180.1"), RCDO = c("671", "667.5"), RENT = c("117.8", "116"
), RGU = c("169.70000000000002", "169.9"), RS = c("261", 
"251.6"), RWA = c("302.5", "302.5"), SDY = c("70.5", "69.75"
), SERC = c("286.10000000000002", "279.8"), SHI = c("166.6", 
"161.1"), SIV = c("199.75", "200"), SKS = c("90", "92"), 
STHR = c("350.25", "358.5"), TK = c("1664", "1635"), TRB = c("170.5", 
"172"), V. = c("609.5", "600"), WOS = c("3242", "3243"), 
XCH = c("188", "184.75"), ARM = c("906", "887.5"), BVC = c("16.38", 
"16.25"), CSR = c("758", "756"), IMG = c("188.5", "184.75"
), LRD = c("309.7", "306.7"), IC = c("298.10000000000002", 
"299"), SEU = c("141", "141"), ST = c("104.60000000000001", 
"99.9"), BATS = c("3482", "3480"), IMT = c("2664", "2679"
)), .Names = c("NA", "AVON", "BA.", "CMRG", "COB", "MGGT", 
"QQ.", "RR.", "SNR", "ULE", "GKN", "BRAG", "BVIC", "CCH", "DGE", 
"SAB", "STCK", "ALNT", "CAR", "CRDA", "ELM", "JMAT", "SYNT", 
"VCTA", "DIA", "DNO", "E2V", "HLMA", "HTY", "MGAM", "OXFD", "RSHW", 
"SXS", "TTG", "XAR", "X", "ABF", "AE", "CARM", "CWK", "DCG", 
"DVO", "GNCL", "HFG", "FD", "TATE", "MNDI", "BI", "REX", "RC", 
"SMDS", "SMIN", "VSVS", "AGA", "BDEV", "BKG", "BLWY", "BVS", 
"CRST", "GLSN", "MCB", "SN", "RB.", "RDW", "TW.", "BODY", "FENR", 
"GDWN", "HILS", "IMI", "MRO", "VAR", "RNO", "RTRK", "SFR", "SRX", 
"TRI", "VTC", "WEIR", "EVR", "FXO", "BBA", "BMS", "CKN", "FSHR", 
"RMG", "STOB", "UKM", "WIN", "GAW", "HTM", NA, "AAL", "ABG", 
"ANTO", "AF", "AQ", "ARMS", "BLT", "CEY", "FRES", "GEMD", "GLEN", 
"HOC", "KAZ", "KMRL", "LMI", "NWR", NA, "DL", "OG", "OLY", "RIO", 
"RRS", "VED", "AFR", "BG.", "B.", "CNE", "ENQ", "EXI", "HDY", 
"JKX", "OHR", "MO", "RDSA", "RDSB", "SIA", "SMDR", "TLW", "AMEC", 
"CIU", "GMS", "HTG", "LAM", "FC", "WG.", "BRBY", "ZC", "SG", 
"TED", "ULVR", "AZN", "BTG", "CIR", "DH", "GNS", "GSK", "HIK", 
"SH", "SK", "VEC", "AGK", "AHT", "ATK", "BAB", "BNZL", "BRAM", 
"BRSN", "CLLN", "CMS", "CNCT", "CI", "CTR", "DCC", "DLAR", "DLM", 
"ECOM", "ESNT", "EXO", "EXN", "GFS", "GFTU", "HAS", "HRG", "HSV", 
"HWDN", "HYC", "IRV", "ITRK", "LVD", "MER", "MMC", "MNZS", "MI", 
"MTO", "NTG", "AY", "FL", "RCDO", "RENT", "RGU", "RS", "RWA", 
"SDY", "SERC", "SHI", "SIV", "SKS", "STHR", "TK", "TRB", "V.", 
"WOS", "XCH", "ARM", "BVC", "CSR", "IMG", "LRD", "IC", "SEU", 
"ST", "BATS", "IMT"), row.names = 7785:7786, class = "data.frame")
```

I am on Mac OS 10.10, R 3.1.1 and RStudio 0.98.1060.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your column names is `NA`. If `d` is your data defined above, then try `names(d)[92]`. Try replacing with a non-missing column name.

Answer (score 1):

As allready mentioned by DMC, but with a short version of your example code.

```
a <- structure(list(`NA` = structure(c(16343, 16344), class = "Date"), 
           AVON = c("615.5", "621.5"),
           BA. = c("471.5", "463.2"),
           `NA` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), AAL = c("1384", "1363.5")),
           .Names = c(NA, "AVON", "BA.", "NA", "AAL"), row.names = 7785:7786, class = "data.frame")


View(a)
Error in View : undefined columns selected

names(a)
[1] NA     "AVON" "BA."  "NA"   "AAL"

a <- structure(list(`NA` = structure(c(16343, 16344), class = "Date"), 
                AVON = c("615.5", "621.5"),
                BA. = c("471.5", "463.2"),
                `NA` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), AAL = c("1384", "1363.5")),
           .Names = c("NA", "AVON", "BA.", "NA", "AAL"), row.names = 7785:7786, class = "data.frame")


View(a)
names(a)
[1] "NA"   "AVON" "BA."  "NA"   "AAL"
```

You need to have proper names in the data frame to View it.